After Completable future timeout and exceptions program keeps executing
I have created the example below to illustrate my problem. Basically I am iterating over two list that contain objects and using completable futures I am kicking off each the method mymethod() on each of the instances of my Test class.I set it such that if I instantiate Test class with a -1 it will throw an exception and if I instantiate with a number bigger than 0 it will do a wait before completing.

class Test {
    int waitSec=0;
    String className;

    public Test(int waitSec, String className) {
        this.waitSec = waitSec;
        this.className = className;
    }

    public void mymethod() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Executing mymethod in "+className);
        System.out.println("before "+className);
        if(waitSec != 0) {
            new CompletableFuture<>().completeAsync(() -> null,
                    CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).join();
        }
        if(waitSec == -1) {
            throw new Exception("aaa"+className);
        }
        System.out.println("after"+className);
    }
}

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        ArrayList<List<Test>> list= new ArrayList<List<Test>>();
        List<Test> myTest1 = new ArrayList<>();
        myTest1.add(new Test(10,"Class1"));
        myTest1.add(new Test(0, "Class2"));
        List<Test> myTest2 = new ArrayList<>();
        myTest2.add(new Test(0, "Class3"));
        myTest2.add(new Test(0, "Class4"));
        list.add(myTest1);
        list.add(myTest2);



        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> cp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Test> myTest : list) {
            for (Test test : myTest) {
                CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        test.mymethod();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>exception<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
                        handleFailure(e,"exception");
                    }
                }, executor);
                future.exceptionally(t -> {handleFailure(t,"timeout");
                    System.out.print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>timeout<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
                    return null;
                });
                //future.orTimeout(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                cp.add(future);
            }
            CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(cp.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
            allOf.orTimeout(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            allOf.get();
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private static void handleFailure(Throwable t, String myString){
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>FAILED<<<<<<<<<<<"+ myString);
    }
}

What I want to accomplish is for the code to stop and return when:

an exception is thrown
or when it times out.
The problem I am having is that even if it timeout, the execution never ends.
I think the reason for that is that either the thread of allOf is still executing but I am not sure. Any ideas?


Your are not calling shutdown() in the exceptional case. You have to put the shutdown() in a finally block, to ensure that it is always executed. Or use try( … ) { … } (with Java 19 or newer)

Thanks, I implemented try catch and ir worked
